# using requests.post to send a request with a certificate

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to send some data via a web based api. The client has given me an example snippet of code to test everything.

My problem below is how to use my certificate.

Their example

```
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, cert=('certificate.cer','keyfile.key'))
```

I tried

```
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, cert=('C:\MyPath\My-certs.p12','password'))
```

However I get the error,

> OSError: Could not find the TLS key file, invalid path: password

I have written a C# example and the code works, so I know the certificate and the other pieces are ok. I just can't get the certificate to work in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your certificate file is P12, which isn't supported by `requests` yet. You have two options:

1. Convert the P12 file into separate public certificate and private key files. For Linux or Mac, use [this](https://serverfault.com/a/641582). Then you can use the separate files as a tuple in `cert`.
2. Use [requests-pkcs12](https://pypi.org/project/requests-pkcs12/) which has support for P12 files:

--

```
from requests_pkcs12 import post
response = post(url, data=data, headers=headers, pkcs12_filename='C:\MyPath\My-certs.p12', pkcs12_password='password')
```